# Primefaces datatable row expansion exporting

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to export datatable row expansion in primefaces but i cannot figure it out. Is there anyway to do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PF version?  The PF exporter does not seem to support rowexpansions check [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17989) and check out [Primefaces Extensions](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/expandableTable.jsf) that does seem to support it to some extend

Comment: PF version is 5.0. Thanks for links, they will be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can export PrimeFaces DataTable with rowExpansion data without an other Java API or you can use custom export method on ManagedBean class with [Apache POI API](http://poi.apache.org/) help.

Here trick is, add the columns which to be exporting to the file and append the visible=”false” attribute to the these columns.
Then append the exportable=”false” attribute to the p:rowToggler column.

Thus, you won’t see datatable columns but you will see these columns on the exported file.

Obtained from [here](https://yazilimcity.net/primefaces-exporting-datatable-with-rowexpansion-data/)

```
<h:form id="myDtTblFrm">

<h:commandLink>
    <img src="../ims/excel.png"/>
    <p:dataExporter type="xlsx" target="myTbl" fileName="myExcelFile"/>
</h:commandLink>

<p:dataTable id="myTbl" var="item" value="#{myBean.list}">

    <p:rowExpansion>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" style="width: 50%">
                    <h:outputText value="Column Header 04" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.property04}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Column Header 05" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.property05}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
    </p:rowExpansion>

    <p:column exportable="false">
            <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Colum01">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{item.property01}" />
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Column02" visible="false" >
        <p:outputLabel value="#{item.property02}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="colum03" >
        <p:outputLabel value="#{item.property03}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="colum04" style="display: none">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{item.property04}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="colum05" style="display: none">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{item.property05}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Please include your code example in the answer itself, instead of linking to it. Links can go dead, or the website they link to might change over time.

Comment: The expanded row takes the colspan to include the hidden column so makes it longer. A great solution if there was a way to reduce the colspan of the rowexpansion by one.